# Coffee consuming amount

Tags: coffee-culture, coffee-shop

What's the amount of coffee per day do we need to drink? I study whole day so I feel coffee addicted while studying so can any one answer me?

Comment: Can you specify your question? Give us some context and some indication what kind of information you are looking for? Because really you don't need to drink any coffee, it's a choice you make and how much you need to keep you caffeinated only you can know. We can't help you with that. You feel it and it probably changes by the day, what you eat, how much you have slept, if you are sick, etc.

Comment: You need to define what you mean. Amount for what? Not being tired? Well that's fairly variable - how much sleep did you get, your caffeine tolerance, etc... I drink way too much coffee and don't feel a thing. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the limit to the amount of coffee one can consume?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/what-is-the-limit-to-the-amount-of-coffee-one-can-consume)

Comment: With your clarification that you are actually asking about maximum dosage, your question becomes a duplicate of [What is the limit to the amount of coffee one can consume?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/2857/what-is-the-limit-to-the-amount-of-coffee-one-can-consume)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevailing wisdom is that it is generally safe to drink up to 4 cups of coffee per day. Caffeine is the world's most widely consumed psychoactive drug (stimulant) and typical consumption is alleged to have a number of positive health benefits.

The U.S. [2015 Dietary Guidelines](https://health.gov/dietaryguidelines/2015/guidelines/) Advisory Committee recommended a similar limit. Lower limits are recommended for pregnant women, adolescents & children.

Lethal caffeine overdoses are rare and estimates of a lethal amount of caffeine in a healthy adult range from 10,000 - 20,000 mg.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to drink any coffee. Water, you need. Coffee, you can live without, even if it doesn't feel much like living.

Answer (score -1):

I am a coffee addict. I drink 10 cups per day. I think you just have to set the time alone. And do not forget to drink water for balance.

Comment: What do you mean by: " I think you just have to set the time alone."

Comment: Sorry, can’t really understand what you are saying - could you [edit] to clarify, please?